# How to make dropdown list selected with loop in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an array as collection and I want to load it within dropdown list & I want a default selection on some condition but I don't know how to achieve this.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-commingsoon',
  templateUrl: './commingsoon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commingsoon.component.css']
})
export class CommingsoonComponent implements OnInit {
  public collection = [];
  constructor() {
    for(let i = 1; i<=10 ; i++) {
      this.collection.push(`Angular: ${i}`);
    }
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<select name="" id="" style="position:relative; left: 100px">
    <option *ngFor="let i of collection;" value="{{i}}" [selected]="i == Angular: 2">{{ i }}</option>
</select>
```

I want the drop down should be selected value of when  i == Angular: 2

Comment: quotes are missing, try `i == 'Angular: 2'`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a typical way of using `ngModel`
This is more convenient if you are going to process selected value afterwards.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
    {{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njs3tz

Answer (score 7):

Quotes are missing, please try `i == 'Angular: 2'`

Or, if you are just interested in the index:

`<option *ngFor="let i of collection; let j = idx" value="{{i}}" [selected]="j === 2">{{ i }}</option>`

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh please mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: This really should be the selected answer, fits the use case I was looking for perfectly